# Adding code (pagebreak) after value change in csvsimple

Tags: conditionals, csv, csvsimple

## Background

I want to create a document with the user data of our network at school, which should be handed out to the user. This should be done class by class.

## Approach

The user data are given in a csv-file. I use `csvsimple` to process them as follows. I know that there are better ways to structure the data as `\newline`, but I want to keep it simple.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{user.csv}
Adam Apfel;5a
Alexander Arthur;5a
Arndt Albrecht;5a
Barbara Boll;5b
Bert Brüller;5b
Brian Blaumann;5b
Charles Chaume;5c
Claude Claudette;5c
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\csvfilename}{user.csv}


\begin{document}

  \csvreader[
    separator=semicolon,
    after line=\newline
  ]
  {\csvfilename}
  {1=\name, 2=\class}
  {
    \name, \class
  }

\end{document}
```

## Problem

I want to print the user class by class. So there should be a pagebreak after the class changes, and I have one (or more) pages for class 5a, one for 5b and so on.

I tried many different things, but nothing worked. My idea (which I deleted after frustration ...) was to create a temporary macro, which saves the current class and compares it with the current class at the next row. But I didn't get it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the actual class from the csv list in a command `\lastclass` and check if the next one is still the same, or then do `\clearpage`.

Be sure to use `\edef` to update the value of `\lastclass` so it's updated in this very moment.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{filecontents*}{user.csv}
Adam Apfel;5a
Alexander Arthur;5a
Arndt Albrecht;5a
Barbara Boll;5b
Bert Brüller;5b
Brian Blaumann;5b
Charles Chaume;5c
Claude Claudette;5c
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\csvfilename}{user.csv}


\begin{document}
  \def\lastclass{}%
  \csvreader[
    separator=semicolon,
    after line=\newline
  ]
  {\csvfilename}
  {1=\myname, 2=\myclass}
  {%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\lastclass}{\myclass}}{}{%
        \clearpage
        \edef\lastclass{\myclass}%
        }
    \myname, \myclass
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

As my knowledge about plain TeX is very limited, I don't know much about expandation and \edef is new to me.